# How do I blur a widget in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, blur

I need to blur a widget, for example, a simple Container.
How do I blur it?

```
new Container(
  child: new Text('hello I am here'),
  height: 100.0,
  width: 100.0,
  color: Colors.red,
)
```

Consider the above Container.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can create a **[Stack](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Stack-class.html)** like:

First child: What you want to blur (in your case: Container)

Second child: [BackdropFilter](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html)

And within the second child (BackdropFilter), there is the parameter child, which is used to insert a widget into the tree, that will not be affected by the BackdropFilter.

In your BackdropFilter, set filter: [ImageFilter.blur](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter/ImageFilter.blur.html)(5.0, 5.0)

5.0 is amount of blur you wish.

Comment: Show the working code for this, please. Also, does it work on Android & all devices you tested?

Comment: Is there a way to either make the Stack wrap to the height of the third child, or have the BackdropFilter match the third child, in a case where the third child can be of a variable height? I have that issue and can't figure a way around it https://stackoverflow.com/q/52253848/3429021

Answer (score 20):

Here is sample code:

```
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

 Widget backdropFilterExample(BuildContext context, Widget child) {
    return Stack(
      fit: StackFit.expand,
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        BackdropFilter(
          filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
            sigmaX: 8.0,
            sigmaY: 8.0,
          ),
          child: Container(
            color: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Google also has sample code on:

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/BackdropFilter-class.html

Answer (score 11):

Note, if you want to blur certain widget instead of all widgets beneath, take a look at [ImageFilter class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/ImageFilter-class.html) instead of BackdropFilter.

For example,

```
Widget _emptyCard() {
return Stack(
  alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
  children: [
    ImageFiltered(
      imageFilter: ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX: 3.0, sigmaY: 3.0),
      child: _fakeBlurredStats(),
    ),
    _noStatsMessage(),
  ],
);
```

}[image]

Answer (score 5):

I use `BackdropFilter` and `Position.fill` examples:

```dart
import 'dart:ui' as ui;

 Widget buildBlur({@required BuildContext context, @required Widget child}) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        child, // Your child
        Positioned.fill(
            child: BackdropFilter(
              filter: ui.ImageFilter.blur(
                sigmaX: 1.0,
                sigmaY: 1.0,
              ),
              child: Center(
               child: XedProgress.indicator(), // replace your loading widget
             ),
           ),
         )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: What is the `child` argument if we need to replace our widget at the commented place?

Comment: yes, child will replace by your widget

Comment: Position.fill worked very well for me, since I need to blur an item in a ListView. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

blur filter widget

```dart
import 'dart:ui';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BlurFilter extends StatelessWidget {
  final Widget child;
  final double sigmaX;
  final double sigmaY;
  BlurFilter({this.child, this.sigmaX = 5.0, this.sigmaY = 5.0});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        child,
        ClipRect(
          child: BackdropFilter(
            filter: ImageFilter.blur(
              sigmaX: sigmaX,
              sigmaY: sigmaY,
            ),
            child: Opacity(
              opacity: 0.01,
              child: child,
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

usage

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:my_app/widgets/blur_filter.dart';

class WidgetToImage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('blur filter'),
      ),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text('123'),
            Text('999'),
            BlurFilter(
              child: Text('1000'),
            ),
            Text('888'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

We need 3 things to make blur widget

- 1.Stack
- 2.BackdropFilter
- 3.ImageFilter.blur

> ```
> Stack(
>      children: <Widget>[
>        Container(child: Text( "Hello")),              // First child
>        BlurryEffect(0.5,0.1,Colors.grey.shade200)    //  Second Child
>      ],
> )
> ```

and,

```
class BlurryEffect extends StatelessWidget {
  final double opacity;
  final double blurry;
  final Color shade;

  BlurryEffect(this.opacity,this.blurry,this.shade);

    @override  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      child: ClipRect(
        child:  BackdropFilter(
          filter:  ImageFilter.blur(sigmaX:blurry, sigmaY:blurry),
            child:  Container(
              width: double.infinity,
              height:  double.infinity,
              decoration:  BoxDecoration(color: shade.withOpacity(opacity)),
             ),
           ),
          ),
        );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I use `onWindowFocusChanged` for detect `onPause` on `MainActivity`

```
    @Override
public void onWindowFocusChanged (boolean hasFocus){
    if (!hasFocus){
        channel.invokeMethod("on_pause", "");
    }

    super.onWindowFocusChanged(hasFocus);
}
```